# Host availability report from nagios\icinga log file

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga, reporting

Is there a way of analyzing and report-building from icinga\nagios log files? 
I tried (avail.cgi) host availability reports but it works so slowly. I should wait 3-5 minutes if I want a week report and apache's timeouts are if I request more period of time.
I tuned apache timeout but it looks like wrong way. 
Any other advices would be helpful

Comment: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Reporting

Comment: Finally, I've chosen Centreon Reporting because I have ICINGA-IDO-CENTREON scheme.